# What database should I use for an application that will be deployed on both Linux (raspb pi) and Android

Tags: linux, android, web, database

I'm building an application that will be deployed on two different platforms simultaneously (Linux (raspb pi) and Android/web). I'm using Python for Linux and either Python or JavaScript for Android/web.

Please what database would link the two platforms? In other words, what database should I use for the application?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi since the database will presumably run on a server, which maybe be any type of computer.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But as already noted your question has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

Use sqlite3, that's well supported in Raspbian. There's also some support in Android. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite